# Trying to load multiple XML input files into iDictionary<string,Ojbect>

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I found one way to build one dictionary from one input file but it doesn't account for multiple input files. To take my efforts to the next step: I wish to append additional input files into the existing hash and also trying something different this code is somewhat close to what I wish to accomplish but it is still missing syntax.

```
        foreach (string file in filePaths)
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(file);

            allDict = (from m in xdoc.Descendants("msg")
                        .ToDictionary(m => m.Element("msgId").Value,
                                      m => new msg
                                      {
                                        msgId = m.Element("msgId").Value,
                                        msgType = m.Element("msgType").Value,
                                        name = m.Element("name").Value
                                      }
            )
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a "master" object, then append the values you get from each file.

```
Dictionary<string, msg> masterDictionary = new Dictionary<string, mgs>();

foreach (string file in filePath)
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(file);
    Dictionary<string, msg> fileDictionary = xdoc
        .Descendants("msg")
        .ToDictionary(m => m.Element("msgId").Value,
                      m => new msg
                           {
                               msgId = m.Element("msgId").Value,
                               msgType = m.Element("msgType").Value,
                               name = m.Element("name").Value
                           });

    //now insert your new values into the master
    foreach(var newValue in fileDictionary)
        masterDictionary.Add(newValue.Key, newValue.Value);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416272/trying-to-load-multiple-xml-input-files-into-idictionarystring-ojbect

Comment: Wow, the first part works without a hitch and works exactly as I hoped. Thanks for taking the time to respond and saving me oodles of time. BTW, is there a reference you used to learn this implementation from or is just pure experience?  I still cannot get the second part to work yet, the Add to master dictionary part. It crashes on the newValue.Value with "System.NullReferenceException - Object Reference not set to an instance of an object". This probably has something to do with the value being an object instead of a simple type.

Comment: @user2741445, no problem. I just have picked this method up from all the time I have spent coding. As for your error, I don't see how you are getting a null reference at that spot. `newValue` should never be `null`.